# Polars: adding a column to an empty dataframe with set schema

Tags: python, python-polars

I created an empty dataframe with a set schema. The schema sets the columns data types. I want to add a single name-matching column (series) to the empty dataframe. But it seems to not like it.

```
# Empty dataframe with a given schema    
df = pl.DataFrame(schema={"my_string_col":str, "my_int_col": int, "my_bool_col": bool})

# Now I try to add a series to it
df = df.with_columns(pl.Series(name="my_int_col", values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

But I get the following error:

```
exceptions.ShapeError: unable to add a column of length 5 to a dataframe of height 0
```

It looks as if Polars isn't able to fill the rest of columns (i.e. my_string_col & my_bool_col) with null values. In Pandas you can do this in multiple ways and I wonder if I am missing something or there's no implementation yet?

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially a `.join` operation

```
col = pl.Series(name="my_int_col", values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

df.join(col.to_frame(), on=col.name, how="outer")
```

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ my_string_col ┆ my_int_col ┆ my_bool_col │
│ ---           ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ str           ┆ i64        ┆ bool        │
╞═══════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 2          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 3          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 4          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 5          ┆ null        │
└───────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add a Series with 5 elements to an empty DataFrame with 0 rows.

```
    import polars as pl

df_new = pl.DataFrame({
    "my_string_col": [None],
    "my_int_col": [1],
    "my_bool_col": [None]
})

dfs = [df_new] * 5

df = pl.concat(dfs)

print(df)
```

output:

```
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ my_string_col ┆ my_int_col ┆ my_bool_col │
│ ---           ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ f64           ┆ i64        ┆ f64         │
╞═══════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
│ null          ┆ 1          ┆ null        │
└───────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Hi Abdulmajeed, I am indeed adding a Series to an empty DataFrame. I have thought of using concat but it means writing more code and thought I could so something similar to pandas i.e. my_pandas_df.assign(my_series). There does not seem to be an option I believe.

Comment: Check the code in my answer, did it work with you accordingly?

Comment: Yes, the code works, but that's not a solution. I knew I could do that but it means writing a lot more code.

Comment: I have edit my answer, how about now ?